# Appending an extension automaticlly if url does not contains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I am using the following Rewrite rule

```
RewriteMap map txt:C:/seo/mapping.txt
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!admin)
RewriteCond ${map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.(?:html|gif|jpg|png)) ${map:$1} [NC,L,NS,QSA]
```

But there are some cases where the URL does not contains an extension

like user should be able to enter either `/xyz.html` or `/xyz`What I need is that if user don't enters an extension then in rewrite rule .html should be automatically appended.

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.(?:html|gif|jpg|png)) ${map:$1\.html} [NC,L,NS,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate these two cases like this:

```
RewriteMap map txt:C:/seo/mapping.txt
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!admin)
RewriteCond ${map:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.(?:html|gif|jpg|png)) ${map:$1} [NC,L,NS,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!admin)
RewriteCond ${map:$1.html|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ ${map:$1.html} [NC,L,NS,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which will capture the filename, and if there is an extension it will capture that too. The filename capture group then has `.html` appended to it. However I have not tested this with multiple `/` in it, but I'm sure you can adapt it as necessary.

[Example on Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/39rnn)

`RewriteRule ^\/(\w+)[.]?(\w)? $1.html [NC,L,NS,QSA]`